# how will display my html file which is the string format in JSF?

Tags: javascript, jsf-2

Can someone help? I am really new to JSF. I just want to know how to Display my Html in   the JSF page. My Html file is in the String Format. Say for example

```
     str="<html>.........<h1> display this portion </h1>........</html>";
```

Can i Use Javascript to display this in my JSF?

Comment: What did you try and what error are you getting? If the xml parsing is causing trouble due to some special characters then put your javascript code in a separate file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of 2 options:

1. `<h:outputText value="#{mrBean.htmlString}" escape="false" />`
2. Or else, just make sure that all the tags in your HTML files are closed properly and all of them must have root tags. Then you can include your file with:

   ```
   <ui:include src="myFile.html" />
   ```

Comment: The `<f:verbatim>` is unnecessary. Even more, it's deprecated in JSF2 because it's a leftover from JSF 1.0/1.1 ages. You can just inline HTML unchanged in the view since JSF 1.2 and for sure also in Facelets.

Comment: @BalusC in certain cases, I think `<f:verbatim>` is still useful. If I'm now wrong, `<ui:include>` expect the included page to be a well-formed XML page. If my included page does not have a root tag that covers the whole page, I will get a `FaceletException`.

Comment: You already have the `<html>` root tag (which should actually be `<ui:composition>`, but that aside). Otherwise, there's always the `<ui:fragment>`.